# how to solve Exception in Ical4j?

Tags: java, ical4j

I am using ical4j for parsing outlook calendar file.When i parse the file it gives the exception as follows

```
Error at line 60:Illegal character in opaque part at index 4: CID:<FFFF__=0ABBFDFEDFCB93A98f9e8a9@medicraft.com.au>
```

How to solve this problem without changing the calendar file.

Comment: Could you post the contents of line 60?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the NOTES_COMPATIBILITY CompatibilityHint this exception should go away. You can do this either programmatically:

CompatibilityHints.setHintEnabled(CompatibilityHints.KEY_NOTES_COMPATIBILITY, true);

or via the following line in the ical.properties added to the classpath:

ical4j.compatibility.notes=true

See the ical4j wiki for further details:

http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Compatibility